# Achieving the Effect of onWindowFocusChanged() with a LifecycleObserver

Tags: android

I'm currently working with a **`LifecycleObserver`** in my Android application and I'm encountering a scenario where I need to achieve the effect similar to **`onWindowFocusChanged()`**. However, as **`LifecycleObserver`** doesn't provide a direct equivalent to **`onWindowFocusChanged()`**, I'm unsure how to proceed.

In my specific case, I'm attempting to perform certain actions when my Activity gains focus, such as displaying a window or handling related UI operations. However, I'm facing difficulties due to the lack of an appropriate lifecycle callback within **`LifecycleObserver`**.

Is there a way to achieve the same effect as **`onWindowFocusChanged()`** using a **`LifecycleObserver`**? If not, what alternatives or workarounds can I consider to ensure that my actions are triggered when the Activity gains focus?

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your assistance!

Since LifecycleObserver doesn't directly provide an equivalent to onWindowFocusChanged(), I attempted to perform certain UI-related actions, such as displaying a window, in the onResume() method of my LifecycleObserver implementation. However, this led to a "android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException" exception, indicating that the window token was not valid.

I was expecting the actions performed in the onResume() method of my LifecycleObserver to execute successfully without encountering any exceptions. However, it seems that the window might not be fully prepared when onResume() is called, resulting in the BadTokenException.

Ultimately, I'm seeking guidance on how to ensure that my UI-related actions can be triggered reliably when the Activity gains focus, either through a workaround within the LifecycleObserver or by utilizing alternative approaches.